# How to sort a column based on exact matches with another column

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, excel-formula

I have an inventory table that looks like this (subset):

```
part number | price | quantity
10115       | 14.95 | 10
1050        | 5.95  | 12
1074        | 7.49  | 8 
110-1353    | 13.99 | 22
```

and i also have another table in sheet 2 that looks like this (subset):

```
part number | quantity
10023       | 1
110-1353    | 3
10115       | 2 
20112       | 1
```

I want to basically subtract the quantities in the second table from the ones in the first table. What is the best way of doing this? I have looked in to VLOOKUP and INDEX MATCH but they are not quite right for this. Would this perhaps actually be better in say an Access DB ?

Answer (score 1):

I have add another two columns next to sheet 1 last column. Let us assume that the second table range is  A1:B5.

**Image:**

[image]

**Formulas:**

Column D:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE),0)
```

Column E:

```
=C2-D2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to tackle this using MS Access, the SQL code might look like this:

```sql
select 
    t1.[part number],
    t1.price,
    t1.quantity - nz(t2.quantity, 0) as qty
from 
    inventory t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.[part number] = t2.[part number]
```

Here, I assume that you have a table called `inventory` and a table called `table2` (change these to suit your database).

A [`left join`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/left-join-right-join-operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb) is used to ensure that all records from `inventory` are returned, regardless of whether a match is found in `table2`, and the [`Nz`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c) function is used to return `0` for records for which there is no `part number` match in `table2`.